# Migrating a PHP application to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a stand alone PHP application. It is a simple Food Search. Has a text box and search button. User inputs a food name and hit search and I return a list of items to them.

I would like to integrate this with a wordpress site. I am using the genesis theme/child theme. How do I approach this?

Should I create a new page template by embedding this PHP app code? and then create a page with this template? or is there a better approach? Any links to useful resource appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want your food search to search items in Wordpress or still remain separate?

Comment: scott it will remain separate. Data comes from a database table.Thanks for your time.

Comment: Vandana's answer is good; that's what I would have said too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes , As per my knowledge , it is the right way to do.

Firstly create a template file in theme folder. There you can place your php code.
Then create page from admin panel and assign that template and run.

It will be helpful because as you create template , you can use wordpress inbuilt functions also.

Thanks